# completely remove/disable top-links-container from the header

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

How do i completely **remove/disable** top-links-container from the header? Hope someone can help me, i've tried a few things without luck.

also this, but that makes it go away, but the layout of the whole website is not good anymore after that:

located `app/design/fronend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout/local.xml`

```
<default>
  <reference name="header">    
    <remove name="top.links">
  </reference>
</default>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can comment the specific code from header.phtml?

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your local.xml :

```
<default>
  <reference name="header">
   <remove name="top.links"/>
   </reference>
</default>
```

if you want to remove perticular link:

1. Customer links:  app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\customer.xml

comment below code :

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
 <label>My Account</label>
  <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
    <title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/>
    <position>10</position>
</action>
```

2. Wishlist Link: app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\wishlist.xml

Comment code :

```
<reference name="top.links">
  <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link"/>
   <action method="addLinkBlock">
    <blockName>wishlist_link</blockName>
   </action>
</reference>
```

3. Cart & Checkout Link :   app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\

Comment code :

```
<reference name="top.links"> 
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link"> 
                <action method="addCartLink"></action> 
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action> 
            </block> 
        </reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do the job (in your local.xml file):

```
<default>
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="top.links"/>
        </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking to remove 'topLinks' from your xml or out of the phtml file. The first thing to do is inside of your theme:

> /yourTheme/template/page/html/header.phtml

Look for the following source:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

If you comment this out, the top links wont appear on the page. You can also remove this through the XML.

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
    <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
</reference>
```